# ^J digraph not found

Tags: vim, digraphs

I ran `:registers` and noticed a `^J` at the end of each line.

```
""   def^J
"0   abc^J
"1   def^J
```

Having never seen it before, I did some research and found [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table) page describing digraphs.

Where I expect to find `^J` however, I find `^@`, and I find the same thing when I run `:digraphs`.

The description to the right tells me it's a linefeed, which makes sense given that `^J` is at the end of the line, but why do both sources map LF to `^@` if `^@` is already assigned to the NULL digraph.

Is this a typo?

**Update:** `LF` gets translated to `NULL`: [source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Newlines_and_nulls_in_Vim_script)

Comment: `:h digraph-encoding` might help : "For the NUL character you will see
"10".  That's because NUL characters are internally represented with a NL
character."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `^J` is the proper representation for a linefeed, while `^@` represents NULL. The documentation issue is probably related to the fact that trying to insert a linefeed literally, by any method, ends up inserting a null character.

I tested the following in insert mode:

```
^V^J
^V010
^Vx0a
^Vo012
^Vu000a
^KLF
```

All of them have the same result of inserting a null character, properly displayed as `^@`. This probably induced the documentation error.

Edit: This limitation of literal insertion is less surprising after learning that Vim uses the linefeed as an internal representation of the null character, as pointed out in yolenoyer's comment.